# formMapper: a field twice in a form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a form where I ask the user to select a movie from a list that already exists on the database , and if the film does not exist in he must add another label from input.

When I did this I have an error of course :

```
    $formMapper

->add('movie', 'sonata_type_model', array('label'=>'Select a movie', 'query' => $myData))

->add('movie', 'text', array('label'=>'or grasp one', 'required'=>false));
```

How do I correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

Add property in your entity and check on add form by your own query like:

```
  /* @var $DM \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
            $DM = $this->getDoctrine();
    $Result = $DM->getRepository('Traffic\ControlBundle\Entity\Movies')->findBy(array('yourfilters' => $yourfilters));

if(count($Result) == 0){
    $formbuilder->add('entityPropertyName','text');
}else{
    $formbuilder->add('field','entity', array('class' => 'TrafficControlBundle:Movies'));
}
```

if movie not exists add text field by that property.

And on submit check if form is valid then set that property value in relational entity.

See this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$item->setMovieTitle($this->getRequest()->request->get('movie_name_field'));

$em->persist($item);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map only one field to the form (managed by sonata) and manage the other by your own:

```
$formMapper

->add('movieList', 'sonata_type_model', array('label'=>'Select a movie', 'query' => $myData, 'mapped' => false))

->add('movie', 'text', array('label'=>'or grasp one', 'required'=>false));
```

Then In your Controller You can get the user choice:

```
 $movieList = $form->get('movieList');
```

Then you can do whatever you want (create or update your object as exemple )